# Проблемы с добавлением комментариев к статье

Tags: python, django

Делаю новостной раздел, а точнее комментарии. В принципе, получилось сделать возможность оставлять комментарии. Но они не подвязываются к таблице с новостью, и поэтому под всеми статьями одни и те же комменты. Ломаю голову, никак не пойму как это исправить(

---

**views.py**

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin, FormView

from .models import *
from .forms import *


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'mainApp/homePage.html', locals())


def news(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mainApp/news.html', locals())


class ArticleDetailView(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Article
    form_class = FormComment
    template_name = 'mainApp/article.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_list'] = Comment.objects.all()
        context['comment_form'] = FormComment()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = FormComment(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            # new_form.article = Article.objects.get(???)
            new_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

---

**models.py**

---

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.urls import reverse

from .utils import *


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    time_to_read = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = from_cyrillic_to_eng(str(self.title))
        if not self.date:
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.time_to_read = reading_time(str(self.text))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.date:
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not self.article:
            pass
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
```

---

**urls.py**

---

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

from . import views
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('news/', views.news, name='news'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Смотрели в базе данных в таблицу комментариев. У них у всех один и тот же id на статью?

Comment: `new_form.article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)` ну так надо же сделать привязку к статье

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, выдаёт такую ошибку Unresolved reference 'slug'

Comment: @gil9red в поле article у них стоит прочерк, когда форма обрабатывается, это поле не заполняется

Comment: @Slad `def post(self, request,slug *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin теперь так: post() got multiple values for argument 'slug'

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin ураа, получилось) сервер перезагрузил и заработало) спасибо огромное)

Comment: @Slad не за что)

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, а не подскажете ещё как отфильтровать комменты, относящиеся только к текущей статье? Я так понимаю, вместо это строчки context['comment_list'] = Comment.objects.all() надо вписать context['comment_list'] = Comment.objects.filter(), но вот что в скобках писать не понимаю(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116600/discussion-between-vadim-sharoikin-and-slad).

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, добавьте это в ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо также перед сохранением формы добавить привязку к статье по `id` или `slug`(В вашем случае slug)

```
def post(self, request,slug *args, **kwargs):
    .....
    new_form.article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
```